# Self power-off using UPS and GPIO

Tags: power, mosfet, raspberry-pi, switching

I'm working on a project that include RPI that needs to be off when not used (cut off the main power for it)

1. Input power 12V
2. Charger Unit has input of 12V and charge a single cell Li-Po battery "VBAT" = 4.2V is connected directly to the battery
3. Boost Unit take the VBAT and convert it to 5V for powering the RPI

Target of analog circuit function:
controlling the power line between the battery and the boost unit

- apply current to boost after pressing the push button SW2
- cut off the current with "RPI_PWR" is set to '1' (take note that the GPIO will set to '0' after the power is cut off)

I based the circuit on charging and discharging the capacitor C13.

When 12V is plugged, and SW2 is pressed, the capacitor will be charged and set the N-CH MOSFET (Q9) as active and allow current to pass thru PNP transistor (Q10) to the boost unit
when the RPI needs to cutoff the power, it will set to '1' the GPIO "RPI_PWR" witch will discharge the capacitor thru the N-Ch MOSFET (Q8)

The current that will run thru the PNP transistor is about 5 A at peak, 1.2 A on steady state.

Please send me your remarks on the schematic before manufacturing the circuit.

thank you

[image: Power GPIO controlled Cut-Off schematic]